# Getting non-stored password from Icedove

Tags: process, memory, password, thunderbird

I've recently changed my mail password (because of Heartbleed), but I've forgotten the new one. When entering the new password in Icedove, I didn't think of clicking "remember password", but the instance of Icedove is still running, and still knows how to connect to the server, so the password must be stored *somewhere* in the process. Of course, it cannot be found in the stored passwords list because I didn't tell Icedove to store it.

My question therefore is:

> Is there any way to recover the password from the running process?

Since this running Icedove process is the only place that has the new password, anything involving closing that process naturally won't work.

I'm using Icedove 17.0.10